# How to identify physical NIC?

Tags: c++, windows, nic

I need to identify physical network interface card's IP address to bind with socket because my app needs to bind only on Ethernet(only on physical NIC).

I used [GetAdaptersInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo) to get the list of Adapters an d it is showing vEthernet adapter information also.

So how to distinguish physical adapter info.

My code is here.([Code source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/iphlp/managing-network-adapters-using-getadaptersinfo))

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO  *pAdapterInfo;
    ULONG            ulOutBufLen;
    DWORD            dwRetVal;

    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);


    if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        free(pAdapterInfo);
        pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(ulOutBufLen);
    }

    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("GetAdaptersInfo call failed with %d\n", dwRetVal);
    }

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
    while (pAdapter) {
        if (pAdapter->Type == MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET)
        {
            if (pAdapter->DhcpEnabled) {
                printf("\tDHCP Enabled: Yes\n");
                printf("\t\tDHCP Server: \t%s\n", pAdapter->DhcpServer.IpAddress.String);
            }
            else
                printf("\tDHCP Enabled: No\n");

            printf("\t***\n");

            printf("Adapter Name: %s\n", pAdapter->AdapterName);
            printf("Adapter Desc: %s\n", pAdapter->Description);
            printf("\tAdapter Addr: \t");
            for (UINT i = 0; i < pAdapter->AddressLength; i++) {
                if (i == (pAdapter->AddressLength - 1))
                    printf("%.2X\n", (int)pAdapter->Address[i]);
                else
                    printf("%.2X-", (int)pAdapter->Address[i]);
            }
            printf("IP Address: %s\n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);
            printf("IP Mask: %s\n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpMask.String);
            printf("\tGateway: \t%s\n", pAdapter->GatewayList.IpAddress.String);


            if (pAdapter->Type == MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET)
                printf("\tIt's an Ethernet NIC\n");
            else if (pAdapter->Type == IF_TYPE_IEEE80211)
                printf("\tIt's an Wifi NIC\n");
        }
        pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;

    }
    getchar();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: As MSDN notes, `GetAdaptersInfo` is deprecated since Windows XP, which itself was obsoleted by Vista, which is also out of support ... you really should update your code.

Comment: I would try `GetIfTable` or `GetIfTable2` instead because they give informations on the underlying physical medium.